# Angular 8, Ionic 4 - Problem with multiple routes to same component

Tags: angular, routes, navigation, components, dynamic-view

The structure of the application is having a single view (`DynamicViewComponent`) that will hold different `contentBlocks` on different routes.

So the problem I'm having trouble with is that when navigating from one route to another, previous instance of the `DynamicViewComponent` is not destroyed. The application start to build up nodes and listeners with every navigation action.
The methods inside the `DynamicViewComponent` are firing as many as navigation clicks were done.

I've tried to clear the `ViewContainerRef`, but that only results in clearing stuff from the DOM, not the actual cached instances from previous routes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to utilize the angular router, inside your `DynamicViewComponent` you should have a `<router-outlet>` where the different content blocks will be placed and in the routes declare the `DynamicViewComponent` as the main path `path: ''`
[image]